# Action of UIButton doesn't work if the button is initialized with let and the addTarget in it in custom view, but it works in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

When I create a button like below **in the custom view** the action does not work:

```
private let usernameButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("someTitle", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapUsername), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

However, it works when I do the same in **UIViewController** somehow.

It always works if I make it **lazy var** but couldn't understand why it doesn't work if I make it let in custom view while It is working in UIViewController

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: What does "the action does not work" mean? What happens? Does your code crash when you tap the button? If it crashes, what is the error message? Or does the button simply do nothing? Where is the method `didTapUsername()` defined? In the view controller, or in the custom view? You need or provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` inside that block actually is the block, not the view(you can see it using `print(self)`), probably because it's not yet initialised(same reason why you can't use self before `super.init`), that's why I usually add targets/delegates outside of the initialisation block. With `lazy var` self is already initialised, so no problem should be there.

I'm not sure why it works at all, seems kind of magic for me, and I wouldn't depend on it.

Anyway, it works fine with both custom ViewController and custom View in my case: I've added `CustomView` as subview to `ViewController` in the storyboard.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let usernameButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("someTitle", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapUsername), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.insertSubview(usernameButton, at: 0)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        usernameButton.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    @objc
    func didTapUsername() {
        print("ViewController", #function)
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView {
    private let usernameButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("someTitle", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapUsername), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addSubview(usernameButton)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        usernameButton.frame = bounds
    }
    
    @objc
    func didTapUsername() {
        print("CustomView", #function)
    }
}
```

This shouldn't do differently for `UIViewController`/`UIView`, check out your logic

Comment: Hello Philip. Appreciated for your attention. What I have noticed after that is, I am actually **only** facing this issue if I am using let for creating an instance of UIButton inside the class inherited from UICollectionViewCell. The code block inside the selector I have created is not working. If I try it inside UICollectionReusableView or inside UIViewController, the let keyword is just fine.

Comment: @yigit I'm not sure what makes a cell different, as I said, `self` is not initialized at the time this block is executed. If you put it into a variable `let a = self`, xcode will show you it's type:  `(CollectionViewCell) -> () -> CollectionViewCell`, I have no idea why this works in some cases, but it's not a good practice to use it, as this behaviour may change in future releases.  Just move `addTarget` to `awakeFromNib`